# Recover part of a file in an old commit

Tags: git

Here's the scenario.

```
commit -am "1 create book.txt
commit -am "2 add content to book.txt"
commit -am "3 delete content from book.txt and replace it new content"
```

Now we want to bring back the content that we added in commit 2 and deleted in commit 3. We've tried to merge commit 2 with commit 3, but this doesn't work. Of course we can just checkout commit 2, copy the content that we deleted, and then paste in again after we checkout commit 3. Is there a way to do this, though, with something similar to merge, rebase, or patch? The end result should have *both* the content that we added in commit 2 *and* the content that we added in commit 3.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "*we want to bring back the content that we added in commit 2 and deleted in commit 3*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what cherry-pick is for.

Use `git cherry-pick commit-2` to replay that commit on top of the current state.